# NP problems with exponentially complex average time solution?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, randomness

Assuming $P \ne NP$, is there a problem such that is NP such that:

- There is always a solution

  - Alternatively, there is [asymptotically almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely#Asymptotically_almost_surely) a solution
- On average, it takes exponential time to solve
- The probability distribution can be any distribution which can be sampled from in polynomial time.

Also, what would such a complexity class be called?

Comment: It is consistent with P$\neq$NP that all problems in NP can be solved in subexponential time.

Comment: Does "given from an entropy source" correspond to "there exists an entropy source" or "for all entropy sources"? ​ If the latter, does that quantifier come before of after "there exists an algorithm"? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Random $k$-SAT with an appropriate clause density fits the bill.

Comment: @RickyDemer I was thinking the ability to flip fair coins.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know.  It's possible that $P \ne NP$ but still all problems can be solved in subexponential time, as Yuval states.  The [Exponential Time Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) is a conjecture that a certain problem requires exponential time to solve, but it's a conjecture -- there's debate among researchers about whether we should expect it to hold or not.

Assuming the ETH, you can find problems that meet your requirements, at least for worst-case hardness: there is asymptotically almost surely a solution, and any deterministic algorithm must have worst-case running time that's exponential in the length of the input.  In particular, ETH implies that every problem in the class [SNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNP_%28complexity%29) takes exponential time to solve.  For instance, 3SAT would qualify.

It sounds like you really want average-case hardness.  There are some natural candidate problems: 3SAT with an appropriate clause density would be one reasonable one.

You could also use cryptographic hardness assumptions from the crypto community, e.g., inverting $f(k) = AES_k(0)$ probably takes exponential time yet is known to have a solution, as far as we can tell given our current state of knowledge.  This gives you a problem with a concrete parameter size, but with standard techniques you can build something asymptotic if you prefer an asymptotic family of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not big on complexity classes and their definitions so this answer might not be correct. My suggestion is too long to fit in a comment, though.

Your description made me think about PPAD(-complete (?)) [introduced by Papadimitriou](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000005800637).

The, as far as I'm aware, most associated problem with PPAD-complete is computing a mixed Nash equilibrium (NE) in two player games. Such NE is not efficiently computable and a problem instance can be generated in polynomial time.

Comment: Why do you think these problems take exponential time to solve?  I don't think there's any known result that PPAD-complete problems take exponential time to solve; as far as I know, it's possible they can all be solved in subexponential time (even if P != NP, etc.).

Comment: @D.W. I don't know. Sorry.